# Get related data with select fields

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.5

I do a query where I have to join two tables because I have to do a where statement in a joined table.

```
$locations = Location::join('location_tag', 'locations.id', '=', 'location_tag.location_id')
              ->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'location_tag.tag_id')
              ->where('locations.cityslug', '=', $cityslug)
              ->where('tags.slug', '=', $tagslug)
              ->get();
```

Later in the view, I want to show all names returned locations in a loop. Furthermore I want to return the name of the services (Services is related to the Locations).

```
@foreach($locations as $location)
  {{$location->name}} 
  @foreach($location->services as $service)
     {{@service->name}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

When I do this, the name of the Tags instead of the location is shown. The reason is, that the table **Location** and the table **Tags** have the fields **name** and **slug**.

Therefore I updated the query and added a select statement.

```
Location::join('location_tag', 'locations.id', '=', 'location_tag.location_id')
              ->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'location_tag.tag_id')
              ->select('locations.name','locations.slug')
              ->where('locations.cityslug', '=', $cityslug)
              ->where('tags.slug', '=', $tagslug)
              ->get();
```

But now, I cannot access the information of the related model **Service**. There are no services for the location. What can I do to also access the services in the 2nd loop when I also use a select in the query?

Comment: what is the schema of both location and tags. It looks like you need to add 'locations.services' to your select statement. E.g. ->select('locations.name','locations.slug','locations.services')

Comment: services is another table. Services is related with n:m to Locations. It is not just a column.